# mySQL - Extract data from command output

Tags: mysql

I am running the following `MySQL` command:

```
SELECT service_id AS SERVICE_ID
     , display_name AS SERVICE_NAME
     , perfdata AS PERF_DATA
  FROM services 
 WHERE display_name LIKE 'Traffic%' 
 LIMIT 10;
```

**The output:**

```
+------------+-------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SERVICE_ID | SERVICE_NAME                              | PERF_DATA                                                                                                |
+------------+-------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|      19563 | Traffic-Interface_Wan__0262495982         |                                                                                                          |
|      19591 | Traffic-Interface_Wan__0262914272         | traffic_in=335,1Bits/s traffic_out=391,7Bits/s                                                           |
|      19571 | Traffic-Interface_Wan__0262243728         | traffic_in=408,4Bits/s traffic_out=449,0Bits/s                                                           |
|      19726 | Traffic-Interface_Wan                     | traffic_in=437,1Bits/s traffic_out=3504,9Bits/s                                                          |
```

I would like to know how to get the traffic values in order to compute the 95th percentile.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: There's no simple method. Use `LOCATE()` and `SUBSTR()` to extract the parts of the `perf_data` value that you want. Why aren't you storing the data in a more reasonable way than text strings?

Comment: E.g. `LOCATE(perf_data, 'traffic_in=') + 11` is the position of the beginning of that value, and `LOCATE(perf_data, ',', LOCATE(perf_data, 'traffic_in='))` is the position of the comma that ends the value.

Comment: Hello Barmar, can you modify the sql query with LOCATE so that I can test it.